# Strange Issue With Entity Relationship in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

This is a very odd one, i'll try to explain with couple of sample entities.

```
class Property{

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $postCode;


    /**
     * @var InstructionToSell
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\InstructionToSell")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $instructionToSell;

}

class InstructionToSell{

    /**
     * @var Property
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Property")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $property;

}
```

So two sample entities, the property can have an instruction to sell entity and vice versa. I then have a very basic post code search method in the repo:

```
/**
     * @param string $postCode
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function searchByPostcode(string $postCode) : ?array{

        $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

        $builder->where(
            $builder->expr()->like('p.postCode',':postCode')
        )->setParameter('postCode',str_replace(' ','','%'.$postCode.'%'));

        return $builder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

It all works fine except for one very strange thing. If say a property had the Uk post code of "YO12 7YA" and we run a search for "YO127YA" then it's bringing back a result, but if we use "YO12 7YA" it's bringing back a result but the instructionToSell is null on the property, but it's not null if i remove the space from the search term.

I'm aware this search isn't the best as it stands, need to strip spaces out of the column as well, but the point i am making is, the same code runs for "YO12 7YA" and "YO127YA" which brings back the same property, but one of them has the relationship matched to the instruction to sell, the other it's null.

Why would this happen? It's exactly the same property it's bringing back.

Comment: Did you try to set mappedBy in the relation?

Comment: yes of course, this only happens when doing a LIKE query, sometimes it will bring back the related entity, other times it's null

Comment: Maybe try experimenting with removing the % prefix or % postfix I remember I had a case once when the search query couldnt not find a client in the database when I provided his full surname and the search phrase was wrapped in % %, removing the leading % fixed it for me so maybe give it a go

Comment: It seems to happen when i have 2 repos doing a search on different tables one after the other, somehow like one is interfering with the other. Weird!

Comment: That should not happen to be honest can you edit your answer to show off your full main code not only the code of 1 repo's function Maybe the issue lies somewhere else